# Kibana Installation - Blank Dashboard

Tags: kibana-4

Kibana is accessible from http://127.0.0.1:5601 but shows a blank page except for top banner. I have tried the installation local to my machine and it works. Maybe, I am not opening certain ports?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the console:

[image]

I can access the following URI: http://127.0.0.1:5601/elasticsearch/_nodes

Installation Notes:

- Elasticsearch 2.1.0
- Kibana 4.3.0
- Both running in a vagrant box. Port 5601 from the guest machine is forwarded to the host machine over ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following at elasticsearch.yml and restarting elasticsearch:

> index.max_result_window: 2147483647

More information on index settings:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html

**Update**

It would seem that this is fixed in the latest release of Elasticsearch (2.1.1) and Kibana (4.3.1):

[Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-2-1-1-and-2-0-2-and-1-7-4-released)

[Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-3-1-and-4-2-2-and-4-1-4)

Comment: This may fix the issue but I haven't tried this fix. However, IMHO, this is also not the right approach to a standard installation of kibana - must be a mistake on the developer's part or could be the result of another bug.

Comment: With this solution I get :  [settings_exception] Failed to parse int setting [index.max_result_window] with value [2147483648]

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error with Kibana 4.2 and Elasticsearch 2.1.

I solved it by downgrading to Elasticsearch 2.0, as advised in: https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-2-0

Comment: Thank you - this combination does work. So, there's nothing wrong with my installation scripts but just the incompatibility kinks that need to be worked out.